# Azure containe app - Support for managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-container-apps

I have an existing [Azure Kubernetes Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/intro-kubernetes) and I'm having a look at [Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/overview) to see if it could be a good move for me.

With AKS, I'm heavily using [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity) for management tasks and also using [pod-identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity) to allow applications to connect to other azure resources without storing credentials.

I tried to find some related documentation for Azure Conter Apps but didn't find anything ? Is it something that is not documented, not supported at the moment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Container Apps went GA, it is now available: [Managed identities in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/managed-identity).

both system-assigned and user-assigned are available.